# Can we avoid multiple if''s?

Tags: c#-3.0

I tried my level best to write an improved version but failed.

```
inFiles.ToList().ForEach(i =>
{
    filePath = inFolder + "\\" + i.Value;

    if (i.Key.Equals(replacementFile))
    {
        replacementCollection = GetReplacementDataFromFile(filePath);
    }
    else if (i.Key.Equals(standardizationFile))    
    {
        standardizationCollection = GetStandardizationDataFromFile(filePath);
    }                   
});
```

The problem is that I cannot use a switch case over here because the comparison variables are not constant.

Kindly help to improve this code.

I am using C#(3.0).

Thanks

Comment: Why do you feel that there is a problem with this?

Comment: I dunno, @Robin, there are a couple weird things about it and at least one bad thing.

Comment: @Newbie  Is that a shortened version of the code for purpose of a question?  If not then I think this code is fine - I understand the code from a quick glance which I think is the main thing.  Long If statements are a potential "code smell" and it is great that you are trying to improve but removing if statements is not a goal in itself.

Comment: Given that the two proposed alternatives (ternary operator, premature continue) have both been implemented incorrectly (on the first try at least), I would say that's pretty good evidence that what you're doing is the clearest, most straightforward way.

Comment: Why are you iterating over inFiles?

Comment: as suggested by others, use: `filePath = Path.Combine(inFolder, i.Value);`

Comment: I'd use a foreach loop to avoid the need for the ToList() call.  I'd also use a lot less vertical space.  But I have no problem with the if-else-if part.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code you have doesn't have an excessive amount of if's.

You appear to have three possibilities: Belongs to replacement, belongs to standardization, Belongs to neither of those. What you have is an efficient, readable way to do it.

I'd keep it the way it is.

Comment: Well... I'd +1 but he needs to fix that path concatenation.

Comment: Sir, actually it is having 5/6 if's.. but I mput only 2

Comment: @Newbie: well that kinda changes things, doesn't it? Please post the full code listing so we can see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Replace Conditional with Polymorphism](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html) refactoring in case you have huge logic.

Comment: For me, creating smart types (user defined types), is on of the most important piece while OO designing systems.i would always think if i have excessive if/else,loops and refactor them to proper types

Comment: My point is that you can't always do that.  `if( length < 3.14159 && ...)` doesn't easily refactor into a type.  It's a value-based condition.

Comment: Agreed, but the logic in the question asked was not asked on value but some type.Agreed conditionals are required for other things like value checks,validations,etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here's another try (and still no explicit if-statements!):

```
inFiles.ToList().ForEach(i =>

{

  filePath = inFolder + "\\" + i.Value;
  replacementCollection = testForReplacement(i,filePath,replacementFile);
  standardizationCollection =  testForStandardization(i,filePath,standardizationFile);
  someOtherCollection_1 =  testForOtherCollection(i,filePath,otherFile);
  ....//more statements like this...
});
...
...
...
Collection testForReplacement(i,filePath,testFile)
{
    return i.Key.Equals(testFile) ? GetReplacementDataFromFile(filePath) :null;
}
Collection testForStandardization(i,filePath,testfile)
{
    return i.Key.Equals(testFile) ? GetStandardizationDataFromFile(filePath) :null;
}
Collection testForSomeOtherCollection(i,filePath,testfile)
{
    return i.Key.Equals(testFile) ? GetOtherDataFromFile(filePath) :null;
}
...///more functions like this...
```

This is more pseudo-code than real code (not sure this will compile as-is) but I hope it makes the point. ;)

This code looks redundant, but it is easy to write a script/macro that can take a list of all the possible file types and generate (or re-generate when the pattern changes) all the necessary functions and statements to use them. Generated code can save a lot of time if you do it right!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for the last element in the list that is a replacement file or a standardisation file.

Im not sure what should happen if there are multiple files of the same type in the collection..

This is not as efficient as you have to go through the list twice.. but perhaps it is more expressive, and if the list of files is small, perhaps just a premature optimisation issue!

```
inFiles.Where(i => i.Key.Equals(replacementFile)).ToList().ForEach( i =>
{
    replacementCollection = GetReplacementDataFromFile(Path.Combine(inFolder, i.Value));
}

inFiles.Where(i => i.Key.Equals(standardizationFile)).ToList().ForEach( i =>
{
    standardizationCollection = GetStandardizationDataFromFile(Path.Combine(inFolder, i.Value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very readable, I don't know what you hope to gain by removing an if. I would leave as is, but maybe add a final else instead of just ending the method. This might throw an exception or log some information.

Answer (score 0):

if inFiles is a dictionary, you could do this :

```
replacementCollection = 
    inFiles.ContainsKey(replacementFile) ? 
        GetReplacementDataFromFile(
            Path.Combine(inFolder, inFiles[replacementFile]) ) : null;

standardizationCollection = 
    inFiles.ContainsKey(standardizationFile) ? 
        GetStandardizationDataFromFile(
            Path.Combine(inFolder, inFiles[standardizationFile]) ) : null;
```

You can make it shorter if your GetReplacementDataFromFile, GetStandardizationDataFromFile can handle empty string parameter gracefully:

```
string value;


replacementCollection = 
    GetReplacementDataFromFile( 
        inFiles.TryGetValue(replacementFile, out value) ? Path.Combine(inFolder, value) : string.Empty );

standardizationCollection = 
    GetStandardizationDataFromFile( 
        inFiles.TryGetValue(standardizationFile, out value) ? Path.Combine(inFolder, value) : string.Empty );
```